# Freeswitch Guide how to get CDR UUID from client side

Tags: asterisk, freeswitch, kamailio, fusionpbx

My system contain:
- Freeswitch server 
- Sip Client: Web using sipjs , mobile react-native using https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip to receive call.

My problem is when call done i need to know the uuid of CDR recently add to Postgres DB of that call to attach some info to that call

I try many way but can not success ex: write http request to select into postgres DB, but can not find exactly which uuid because one extension can make many call one time.

Can anyone help me solve this case?

Answer (score 0):

Mark each call with custom variable like callid

Send that to your app via any method, as sipheader, as sip message, using http post etc.

But you also can just search cdr by start date.

Comment: how to send info to client as sipheader or sip message, i try many way but not success, thanks

Comment: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Sofia+SIP+Stack#SofiaSIPStack-AddingRequestHeaders